# WordPress : using page template to fetch posts in wp page

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to display posts in wp page. to do that this is what i did i created a template  named **mypage-page.php** and  copied code from **page.php** to **mypage-page.php**

this is my mypage-page.php

```
          <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
                   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                            <p>Sorry, no posts to list</p>

                    <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
       //   this has header and footer as well .
```

now i created a page  **mytest** using this template ,what i expect it should list posts but it does not, please help me to understand where i'm wrong . 
i'm just a beginner

Comment: You probably have to reset the post object. This question can live here but you will probably find more success on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

If your page is a Custom Page template then you have initialise a custom query.
WordPress's default query won't work in a custom page template.

You can do that query using WP_Query Class :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Or 
get_posts() :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

I'd suggest the earlier one.

Comment: one more thing i created template named page-mytest and it fetches only post named mytest . what should be name of the template so that it may render all posts ? or there is anyother issue with it

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this, [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)